# DocuSign broken Webhook online documentation

Tags: docusignapi

I can't report this to Docusign (raise support ticket) as I only have a Sandbox test account.

I'm testing their product.

Would be nice to read the Docs, but they are broken!!!

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status

**returns
404**

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this broken link and will fix this ASAP
In the meantime, you can use this link instead:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/v2/code-examples/webhook-status